# Quarkus amazon lambda JAX-RS integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, jax-rs, aws-api-gateway, quarkus

As far as I understand the quarkus-amazon-lambda extension allows to write Lambdas using `com.amazonaws...RequestHandlers` that utilize the quarkus features like CDI and the MicroProfile specs.

It would be nice if it also allows to map API Gateway requests to JAX-RS endpoints. For instance it could map all proxied requests to matching resources. So for Lambdas used by HTTP it would be sufficient to just implement JAX-RS resources instead of RequestHandlers.

Is this possible already? Would that be hard to implement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently wrapping up implementing generic JAX-RS/SAM integration, actually.  I'm hoping it'll be done in the next day or two and ready for the next release.

Comment: Thanks @evanchooly. Looking forward to your results.

Comment: Would that also allow for serverless framework integration?

Comment: it would be related very strongly and *probably* allow for it.  It's on my radar but it might be a two step process.  I'm hoping for one but can't make any promises.